# PHP mysql queries to fill a bar chart The Last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a bar graph to fill that wants 7 sums 1 for each day of the week, Monday - Sunday.

Monday being the start of the work week and Sunday being the last day of the week.

the data in the database looks like this.

```
user1|2013-04-13 16:53:55|1
user1|2013-03-13 16:53:55|1
user1|2013-03-13 15:53:55|1
user1|2013-02-13 09:53:55|1
user1|2013-04-13 07:53:55|1
user2|2013-03-13 15:53:55|1
```

The number of rows is the sum for each user

Here is a method for finding out the days of the week.

```
    //find day of week 
    $dayofweek = date('l', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));

    $dates = array(); 
    if ($dayofweek == "Monday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday this week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday this week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday this week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday this week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));     
    }
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Tuesday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday this week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday this week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));      
    } 
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Wednesday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday this week' )); 
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));     
    }
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Thursday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));      
    } 
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Friday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));      
    } 
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Saturday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday last week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday last week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday this week' ));      
    }
    elseif ($dayofweek == "Sunday") {
      $dates['monday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['monday']['evening']= date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Monday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['tuesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Tuesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['wednesday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Wednesday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['thursday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Thursday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['friday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Friday last week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Saturday last week' ));
      $dates['saturday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Saturday last week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['morning'] = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00:01', strtotime( 'Sunday last week' ));
      $dates['sunday']['evening'] = date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'Sunday last week' ));      
   }
```

Should I create seven queries 1 for each day of the week?

```
SELECT myDateTime FROM `mylog` WHERE myDateTime >= $dates['monday']['morning'] AND myDateTime <= $dates['monday']['evening']
```

Or is there an easier more efficient way?

Thanks.

========================EDIT 1============================

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT date( myDateTime ) , sum( myValue )
FROM mylog
GROUP BY date( myDateTime )
```

How do I specify the date I want like a Monday?

Is there a way to make this into 1 query instead of 7?

Thanks.

Comment: wow that's painful to look at

Comment: Yep.. I know but it works but I would like to know a better way, so instead of just asking and not providing any code, at least I did try first.

Comment: well kudos for that, but i'm not sure what the desired output is based on that code, cant you just do group by day in the query?

Comment: I am not really used to doing group by statements... I guess it could work but would I still need 7 queries 1 for each day? or could we use alias some how to  only run 1 query?

Comment: should be achievable with a single querry

Comment: I have updated under Edit 1.. got any ideas?  This works but It works with everything.. i only want the last 7 days.  With each date as returned value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28220/discussion-between-david-eaton-and-dagon)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want might be this.  Although I might be wrong

```
SELECT user, DAYOFWEEK(myDateTime) as day_of_week, SUM(myValue) as total
FROM mylog
WHERE myDateTime >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, "%Y-%m-%d")
GROUP BY user, DAYOFWEEK(myDateTime)
```

Hopefully that's fairly self-explanatory?  The WHERE clause gives you all records in the last week, and the GROUP BY will group first by user, then the day of the week (1 = Sunday).  Manual is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek for this stuff.  So you should end up with something like

```
user  |  day_of_week  |  total
------+---------------+-------
user1 | 1             | 23
user1 | 2             | 14
...
user1 | 7             | 65
user2 | 1             | 12
user2 | 2             | 78
```

and so on.  That seems to be what you're asking right at the start?